# Undefined reference when using SDL_ttf

Tags: compiling, c++, code-blocks, sdl

I am having issues with SDL_ttf, I am new in this type of library so the code below is from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15.tar.gz -> `showfont.c`

```
/*
  showfont:  An example of using the SDL_ttf library with 2D graphics.
  Copyright (C) 2001-2019 Sam Lantinga <slouken@libsdl.org>

  This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
  warranty.  In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
  arising from the use of this software.

  Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
  including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
  freely, subject to the following restrictions:

  1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
     claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
     in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
     appreciated but is not required.
  2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
     misrepresented as being the original software.
  3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
*/

/* A simple program to test the text rendering feature of the TTF library */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"

#define DEFAULT_PTSIZE  18
#define DEFAULT_TEXT    "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
#define WIDTH   640
#define HEIGHT  480

#define TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE \
"Usage: %s [-solid] [-shaded] [-blended] [-utf8|-unicode] [-b] [-i] [-u] [-s] [-outline size] [-hintlight|-hintmono|-hintnone] [-nokerning] [-fgcol r,g,b,a] [-bgcol r,g,b,a] <font>.ttf [ptsize] [text]\n"

typedef enum
{
    TextRenderSolid,
    TextRenderShaded,
    TextRenderBlended
} TextRenderMethod;

typedef struct {
    SDL_Texture *caption;
    SDL_Rect captionRect;
    SDL_Texture *message;
    SDL_Rect messageRect;
} Scene;

static void draw_scene(SDL_Renderer *renderer, Scene *scene)
{
    /* Clear the background to background color */
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, scene->caption, NULL, &scene->captionRect);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, scene->message, NULL, &scene->messageRect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

static void cleanup(int exitcode)
{
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(exitcode);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *argv0 = argv[0];
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    TTF_Font *font;
    SDL_Surface *text = NULL;
    Scene scene;
    int ptsize;
    int i, done;
    SDL_Color white = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0 };
    SDL_Color black = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0 };
    SDL_Color *forecol;
    SDL_Color *backcol;
    SDL_Event event;
    TextRenderMethod rendermethod;
    int renderstyle;
    int outline;
    int hinting;
    int kerning;
    int dump;
    enum {
        RENDER_LATIN1,
        RENDER_UTF8,
        RENDER_UNICODE
    } rendertype;
    char *message, string[128];

    /* Look for special execution mode */
    dump = 0;
    /* Look for special rendering types */
    rendermethod = TextRenderShaded;
    renderstyle = TTF_STYLE_NORMAL;
    rendertype = RENDER_LATIN1;
    outline = 0;
    hinting = TTF_HINTING_NORMAL;
    kerning = 1;
    /* Default is black and white */
    forecol = &black;
    backcol = &white;
    for (i=1; argv[i] && argv[i][0] == '-'; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-solid") == 0) {
            rendermethod = TextRenderSolid;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-shaded") == 0) {
            rendermethod = TextRenderShaded;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-blended") == 0) {
            rendermethod = TextRenderBlended;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-utf8") == 0) {
            rendertype = RENDER_UTF8;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-unicode") == 0) {
            rendertype = RENDER_UNICODE;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-b") == 0) {
            renderstyle |= TTF_STYLE_BOLD;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-i") == 0) {
            renderstyle |= TTF_STYLE_ITALIC;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-u") == 0) {
            renderstyle |= TTF_STYLE_UNDERLINE;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0) {
            renderstyle |= TTF_STYLE_STRIKETHROUGH;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-outline") == 0) {
            if (sscanf (argv[++i], "%d", &outline) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE, argv0);
                return(1);
            }
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-hintlight") == 0) {
            hinting = TTF_HINTING_LIGHT;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-hintmono") == 0) {
            hinting = TTF_HINTING_MONO;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-hintnone") == 0) {
            hinting = TTF_HINTING_NONE;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-nokerning") == 0) {
            kerning = 0;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-dump") == 0) {
            dump = 1;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-fgcol") == 0) {
            int r, g, b, a = 0xFF;
            if (sscanf (argv[++i], "%d,%d,%d,%d", &r, &g, &b, &a) < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE, argv0);
                return(1);
            }
            forecol->r = (Uint8)r;
            forecol->g = (Uint8)g;
            forecol->b = (Uint8)b;
            forecol->a = (Uint8)a;
        } else
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-bgcol") == 0) {
            int r, g, b, a = 0xFF;
            if (sscanf (argv[++i], "%d,%d,%d,%d", &r, &g, &b, &a) < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr, TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE, argv0);
                return(1);
            }
            backcol->r = (Uint8)r;
            backcol->g = (Uint8)g;
            backcol->b = (Uint8)b;
            backcol->a = (Uint8)a;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE, argv0);
            return(1);
        }
    }
    argv += i;
    argc -= i;

    /* Check usage */
    if (!argv[0]) {
        fprintf(stderr, TTF_SHOWFONT_USAGE, argv0);
        return(1);
    }

    /* Initialize the TTF library */
    if (TTF_Init() < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize TTF: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return(2);
    }

    /* Open the font file with the requested point size */
    ptsize = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {
        ptsize = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (ptsize == 0) {
        i = 2;
        ptsize = DEFAULT_PTSIZE;
    } else {
        i = 3;
    }
    font = TTF_OpenFont(argv[0], ptsize);
    if (font == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load %d pt font from %s: %s\n",
                    ptsize, argv[0], SDL_GetError());
        cleanup(2);
    }
    TTF_SetFontStyle(font, renderstyle);
    TTF_SetFontOutline(font, outline);
    TTF_SetFontKerning(font, kerning);
    TTF_SetFontHinting(font, hinting);

    if(dump) {
        for(i = 48; i < 123; i++) {
            SDL_Surface* glyph = NULL;

            glyph = TTF_RenderGlyph_Shaded(font, i, *forecol, *backcol);

            if(glyph) {
                char outname[64];
                SDL_snprintf(outname, sizeof(outname), "glyph-%d.bmp", i);
                SDL_SaveBMP(glyph, outname);
            }

        }
        cleanup(0);
    }

    /* Create a window */
    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, &window, &renderer) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer() failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        cleanup(2);
    }

    /* Show which font file we're looking at */
    SDL_snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "Font file: %s", argv[0]);  /* possible overflow */
    switch (rendermethod) {
    case TextRenderSolid:
        text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, string, *forecol);
        break;
    case TextRenderShaded:
        text = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, string, *forecol, *backcol);
        break;
    case TextRenderBlended:
        text = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, string, *forecol);
        break;
    }
    if (text != NULL) {
        scene.captionRect.x = 4;
        scene.captionRect.y = 4;
        scene.captionRect.w = text->w;
        scene.captionRect.h = text->h;
        scene.caption = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, text);
        SDL_FreeSurface(text);
    }

    /* Render and center the message */
    if (argc > 2) {
        message = argv[2];
    } else {
        message = DEFAULT_TEXT;
    }
    switch (rendertype) {
        case RENDER_LATIN1:
            switch (rendermethod) {
            case TextRenderSolid:
                text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, message, *forecol);
                break;
            case TextRenderShaded:
                text = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(font, message, *forecol, *backcol);
                break;
            case TextRenderBlended:
                text = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message, *forecol);
                break;
            }
            break;

        case RENDER_UTF8:
            switch (rendermethod) {
            case TextRenderSolid:
                text = TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid(font, message, *forecol);
                break;
            case TextRenderShaded:
                text = TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded(font, message, *forecol, *backcol);
                break;
            case TextRenderBlended:
                text = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, message, *forecol);
                break;
            }
            break;

        case RENDER_UNICODE:
        {
            Uint16 *unicode_text = SDL_iconv_utf8_ucs2(message);
            switch (rendermethod) {
            case TextRenderSolid:
                text = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid(font, unicode_text, *forecol);
                break;
            case TextRenderShaded:
                text = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Shaded(font, unicode_text, *forecol, *backcol);
                break;
            case TextRenderBlended:
                text = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Blended(font, unicode_text, *forecol);
                break;
            }
            SDL_free(unicode_text);
        }
        break;
    }
    if (text == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't render text: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        TTF_CloseFont(font);
        cleanup(2);
    }
    scene.messageRect.x = (WIDTH - text->w)/2;
    scene.messageRect.y = (HEIGHT - text->h)/2;
    scene.messageRect.w = text->w;
    scene.messageRect.h = text->h;
    scene.message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, text);
    printf("Font is generally %d big, and string is %d big\n",
                        TTF_FontHeight(font), text->h);

    draw_scene(renderer, &scene);

    /* Wait for a keystroke, and blit text on mouse press */
    done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        if (SDL_WaitEvent(&event) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "SDL_PullEvent() error: %s\n",
                                SDL_GetError());
            done = 1;
            continue;
        }
        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                scene.messageRect.x = event.button.x - text->w/2;
                scene.messageRect.y = event.button.y - text->h/2;
                scene.messageRect.w = text->w;
                scene.messageRect.h = text->h;
                draw_scene(renderer, &scene);
                break;

            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = 1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(text);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(scene.caption);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(scene.message);
    cleanup(0);

    /* Not reached, but fixes compiler warnings */
    return 0;
}

/* vi: set ts=4 sw=4 expandtab: */
```

And when I build in CodeBlocks it gives me the following build log:

```
g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/a obj/Debug/main.o  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf  
/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so: undefined reference to `SDL_RWclose'
/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so: undefined reference to `SDL_RWread'
/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so: undefined reference to `SDL_RWtell'
/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so: undefined reference to `SDL_RWseek'
/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so: undefined reference to `SDL_RWsize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what version of SDL2 are you using? according to [this changelog](https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/WhatsNew.txt) these used to be macros, and only became functions in SDL2 version 2.0.10

Comment: To check the SDL version I used a SDL function named `void SDL_GetVersion(SDL_version* ver)` and It said :                                        `We compiled against SDL version 2.0.10 ...
But we are linking against SDL version 2.0.10.`

Comment: OK so then it should work - I'm curious why you have multiple versions of the same library on the link line though - I wonder if the problem is simply the last `-lSDL2_ttf`? (The correct order is probably just `-lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2` since symbols in libSDL2_ttf likely depend on those in the base libSDL2 library but not vice versa)

Comment: I change the order it stills says `undefined reference` maybe is the code because when I compile the code from (http://www.programmersranch.com/2014/03/sdl2-displaying-text-with-sdlttf.html) it build just fine but when executing it says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: I am not sure why You did not install the SDL2 using apt like `sudo apt install libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libsdl2-ttf-dev` this way You would have a library that was tested and should work out-of-the-box. Try it.